# Spring cloud Microservices on Azure Service Fabric

Tags: spring, azure, microservices

I am new to Microsoft Azure. I have worked on Microservices on Pivotal Cloud Foundry. 
Can we deploy and run Spring Cloud Microservices on Azure Service Fabric? 
Do they work same way as they run on Pivotal Cloud Foundry without any program changes?